# js mobile printing by APD

Tags: javascript

Im use ZEBRA iMZ320 mobile printer and MC3110 (WM). Use Bluetooth connection.
My js code is:

```
function print(str) { 
  var printerID = 'BZ:1|0022583CBD61';  
  apd.PSExternal(261, printerID);   
  apd.PSExternal(270, ""); 

  str   = '^XA^MMT^PW559^LL050^LS0^FT27,40^A@N,15,15,TT0003M_^FH^CI28^FH^FDАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХТЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхтцчшщьъэюя^FS^CI0^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ'

  apd.PSExternalEx(266, str);    
  apd.PSExternal(271, "");
}
```

Right printing only part of string - `'РСТУФХТЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмноп'`.
Parts `'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОП'` and `'рстуфхтцчшщьъэюя'` not printing or printing ubnormaly.
But from Zebra setup Utility this zpl command printing all right. Also it printing right by using rhomobile bluetooth device capability technology

```
> (send_string('^XA^MMT^PW559^LL050^LS0^FT27,40^A@N,15,15,TT0003M_^FH^CI28^FH^FDАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХТЦЧШЩЬЪЭЮЯабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхтцчшщьъэюя^FS^CI0^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ'))
```

. 
Im try to print my russian symbols by use unicode codes of characters in UTF-8(like \u04011) but it is not give good result.

Can anybody help me to decide this task?